# AttributeError| Model object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

This is my model

```
class Leave_Management(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey('employeeModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    reason = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    date_to = models.DateField(null=True)
    date_from = models.DateField(null=True)
    leave_balance = models.IntegerField(default=14)
    paid_leave = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    unpaid_leave = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    time_generated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_approved = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('approve',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.employee)

    def get_total_days(self):
        dt = (self.date_to - self.date_from).days
        return dt
```

I have created two instances of above model. So when i try to access those instances in Django Shell it works fine

```
>>> form = Leave_Management.objects.all().get(pk=1)
>>> form
<Leave_Management: Emp001>
```

But when i  try such thing in views.py It raises error that  E

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Leave_Management' object has no attribute 'get'
```

views.py

```
def approve(request,pk):
    form = Leave_Management.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return form
```

Is there anything wrong in my views.py?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return an instance directly from a view, you need to return a response. Usually that is by rendering a template:

```
return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'form': form})
```

although conceivably you could return the form itself wrapped in an HttpResponse:

```
return HttpResponse(form)
```

but it would look horrible.

(Also you should think about calling things what they are; a model instance is not a form.)